# How to make HTTP POST request with url encoded header and body in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, api, http, dart, post

I've been trying to make a post request to an endpoint that requires both the request header and body to be encoded however so far the responses I've been getting back are 400 errors. The only way I've gotten the request to work so far is with a curl request and Thunder client in VSCode. Below is my request body. Any sort of help would be appreciated thanks.

With the flutter http package:

```
Response response = await post(
      Uri.parse(URL), 
      headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode('$ID:$SECRET'))}',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }, 
      encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
      body: {
      'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
      'refresh_token': refreshToken,
      'redirect_uri':
          redirectUri,
      }
    );
```

Error:

[image]

With the flutter Dio package:

```
Dio.Dio dio = Dio.Dio();
    Dio.Response response = await dio.post(
        URL,
        data: {
          'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
          'refresh_token': refreshToken,
          'redirect_uri':
              redirectUri,
        },
        options:
            Dio.Options(contentType: Dio.Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType, headers: <String, String>{'Authorization': 'Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode('$ID:$SECRET'))}'}));
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply providing `body: 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$refreshToken&redirect_uri=$redirectUri'` ? Afaik that's what x-www-form-urlencoded expects

Comment: still getting the same 400 error message

Comment: As your getting responce back from the server 400 so api is hitting server. Try debug from backend to know exact issuse in detail.